# How to query a list of OpenData end points

Tags: opendata, socrata, soda

How can a query to get a list of end-points provided by a OpenData site using Socrata?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to grab that is using `/data.json` to get a listing of all the datasets on the domain. [Here's an example](https://www.runscope.com/public/bff63de8-1862-45a9-888d-2b10741eacfa/1404c042-021e-43aa-a212-5b76a12b0266) for [data.seattle.gov](http://data.seattle.gov).

That will list all the datasets on that domain. The identifiers listed in data.json can then be used with our [SODA API Endpoints](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/endpoints.html).